# Java: BufferedReader Keeps Writing Values 128-159 as 63 When Converting to Char

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I am trying to write a hex editor. I'm trying to store values by writing a char to a text file. For some reason every decimal number 128-159 is being written or read (not sure which) as 63. I took measures to isolate the problem. Here's an example of it happening:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class Why {

    public static File file = new File("why.txt");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        if(!file.exists())
            file.createNewFile();

        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        bw.write((char) 144);
        bw.close();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        System.out.println(br.read());
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

I figured it out using a FileOutputStream and FileInputStream. Thanks all.

Comment: Can you paste what's inside the file?

Comment: How can you not know if it's written or read as such? Just look at the file.

Comment: Why are you casting `c` to type `char`?  According to [the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write(int)), the version of `write()` you are using expects an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `FileReader` and `FileWriter`, they will use the default encoding for your platform. That's almost *always* a bad idea.

In your case, it seems that that encoding doesn't support [U+0092](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0092/index.htm), which is fairly reasonable given that it's a private use character - many encodings won't support that. I suspect you don't *actually* want `(char) 144` at all. If you really, really want to use that character, you should use an encoding which can encode all of Unicode - I'd recommend UTF-8.

It's important to differentiate between text and binary, however - if you're really just interested in *bytes*, then you shouldn't use a reader or writer at all - use an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream`. Hex editors are typically byte-oriented rather than text-oriented, although they may provide a text view as well (ideally with configurable encoding). If you want to know the exact bytes in the file, you should definitely be using `FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 3):

Character 63 is `?` which means that you're using an encoding that doesn't support the character that you're attempting to write (and replacing it with `?`).

This is the part where you should stop with your hex editor for a while and learn the magical (and terrible) world of character encodings, and why you can't ignore them.

Here's a great read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) and it's still as valid as back in 2003.

Comment: Absolutely! Always specify the character set you want to use when creating Reader or Writer instances.  Non-ASCII codepoints like 144 is not contained in all character sets.

Comment: Or, even better, if this is supposed to be a hex editor, forget Reader and Writer, work with binary InputStream and OutputStream.

Comment: Indeed, the Reader/Writer was his first mistake.